# Looking to convert an console app to a asap.net web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, webforms, ocr

I currently have this console app that extracts words from an image using Microsoft's Optical Character Recognition (OCR). the results currently post into a console app, I want to create the same thing but for a web page form. What's the best way to do that? Can I use a list box or a label to show the results instead of console.writeline?

here's the code for the console app

```
static class Program{ 

    // Add your Computer Vision subscription key and endpoint to your environment variables.
    const string subscriptionKey = ("********");    const string endpoint = ("https://wesam.cognitiveservices.azure.com/");

    // the OCR method endpoint
    static string uriBase = endpoint + "vision/v2.1/ocr";

    static async Task Main()
    {
        // Get the path and filename to process from the user.
        Console.WriteLine("Optical Character Recognition:");
        Console.Write("Enter the path to an image with text you wish to read: ");
        string imageFilePath = @"C:\Users\alabe\Downloads\Syria.jpg";


        if (File.Exists(imageFilePath))
        {
            // Call the REST API method.
            Console.WriteLine("\nWait a moment for the results to appear.\n");
            await MakeOCRRequest(imageFilePath);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid file path");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress Enter to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the text visible in the specified image file by using
    /// the Computer Vision REST API.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="imageFilePath">The image file with printed text.</param>
    static async Task MakeOCRRequest(string imageFilePath)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            // Request headers.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
                "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

            // Request parameters. 
            // The language parameter doesn't specify a language, so the 
            // method detects it automatically.
            // The detectOrientation parameter is set to true, so the method detects and
            // and corrects text orientation before detecting text.
            string requestParameters = "language=unk&detectOrientation=true";

            // Assemble the URI for the REST API method.
            string uri = uriBase + "?" + requestParameters;

            HttpResponseMessage response;

            // Read the contents of the specified local image
            // into a byte array.
            byte[] byteData = GetImageAsByteArray(imageFilePath);

            // Add the byte array as an octet stream to the request body.
            using (ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
            {
                // This example uses the "application/octet-stream" content type.
                // The other content types you can use are "application/json"
                // and "multipart/form-data".
                content.Headers.ContentType =
                    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

                // Asynchronously call the REST API method.
                response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
            }

            // Asynchronously get the JSON response.
            string contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // Display the JSON response.
            Console.WriteLine("\nResponse:\n\n{0}\n",
                JToken.Parse(contentString).ToString());



            Rootobject r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(contentString);

            foreach (Region region in r.regions)
            {
                foreach (Line line in region.lines)
                {
                    foreach (Word word in line.words)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(word.text);
                        Console.Write("");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }





            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + e.Message);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the contents of the specified file as a byte array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="imageFilePath">The image file to read.</param>
    /// <returns>The byte array of the image data.</returns>
    static byte[] GetImageAsByteArray(string imageFilePath)
    {
        // Open a read-only file stream for the specified file.
        using (FileStream fileStream =
            new FileStream(imageFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            // Read the file's contents into a byte array.
            BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream);
            return binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)fileStream.Length);



        }


    }

}
```

Comment: `Can I use a list box or a label to show the results instead of console.writeline?` -- Yes.

Comment: How would I go about this? any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should learn how Web Forms works (assuming you really want to use Web Forms, which is a dead technology). There are tutorials out there. Go try them. Learn it. Then try to implement your project using what you've learned. If you get stuck, provide a [MCVE] and clearly explain where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of chasing down Web Forms, try using Blazor and .Net Core. You still get to re-use your existing C# code. Quick tutorial here: [Blazor Tutorial](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/aspnet/blazor-tutorial/intro)

Starting a new Blazor app (provided you have .Net core installed) is as simple as running one of the following commands from powershell in a folder of your choosing.

```
//serverside (renders views on server and syncs to client) 
dotnet new blazorserver 

//clientside (c# is transpiled to webassembly and runs purely in client browser - still finicky but YMMV) 
dotnet new blazorwasm
```

You could use that existing working project as a springboard to learn a new technology, and gets you up and running fast.

I have followed the following article for getting file uploads, and you could customize example to get image bytes. [blazor-inputfile](https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2019/09/13/blazor-inputfile/)